# Can we use in the distribution of a discrete random variable, the probability of a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

### The exercise

A focus consists of $20$ bulbs that operate independently.

The lifetime of each bulb is a continuous random variable $X$, whose density function is as follows:

$$\displaystyle F_X(x)=1-e^{-\dfrac{x}{50}}$$$$x>0$$

When more than $2$ light bulbs are failed, the maintenance service is called to renew the focus.

What is the probability that in $10$ days the maintenance service is not required?

### My solution

*-I will use in the distribution of a discrete random variable, the probability of a continuous random variable-*

Let Y be the number of bulbs that do not function when analyzing $n=20$ of them, each with an independent probability $p=1-F_X(x)$ to fail, that is: not having $x$ days of useful life. Then, $Y$~$B(n,p)$ so that:

$$\displaystyle f_Y(x,y)=C_y^{20}(1-F_X(x))^y(F_X(x))^{20-y}$$$$x>0$$$$y=0,...,20$$

And if all of the above was right, the probability would be:

$$1-P(Y>2)=P(Y≤2)=f_Y(10,0)+f_Y(10,1)+f_Y(10,2)$$

**Is it okay to do what I did? The solution is correct?** Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, your approach is okay. However, do notice that your $f(x,y)$ is the probability that *exactly* $y$ of the $20$ bulbs will expire *after* $x$ days.

$$\begin{align} f_Y(x,y) &= \mathrm C_y^{20} \,\mathsf P(X>x)^y\,\mathsf P(X\leq x)^{20-y}
\\[1ex] & = \mathrm C_y^{20}\big(1-F_X(x)\big)^y\big(F_X(x)\big)^{20-y}\end{align}$$

For the maintanence *not* to be required you need *less than* three of the twenty bulbs to expire *within* the ten day period.   That is that *no less than* 19 survive.

That is, you seek: $f(10,20)+f(10,19)+f(10,18)$

That is all.

Comment: But $Y$ represents the number of failed bulbs. When $(Y> 2)$ then maintenance is called. But we want to know what the probability is that they do not need the maintenance, so it would be $1-P(Y>2)=P(Y≤2)=f_Y(10,0)+f_Y(10,1)+f_Y(10,2)$. I am right?

Comment: $\mathsf P(X>x)^y$ is the probability that a set of $y$  bulbs all survive $x$ days without failure.  Your function $f_Y(x,y)$ does not measure what you intended.